# Javascript - Make an element dissapear if an option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of countries in a drop-down menu

```
<select name="country_list" id="countries"><option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2" selected="">Canada</option>
<option value="3">Rest of the World</option>

<p><input type="text" name="state_field" value="" id="state"></p>
```

My goal is: If value 3 is selected, the input field "state" disappears. If option 1 or 2 are selected, it should show the field "state".

In case the user has already entered a value in the input field "state" (because option 1 or 2 were previously selected) and he changes it to option 3, the code should first erase the value entered in the state field and then make that field disappear.

How would the Javascript code look like?

I appreciate your help!

UPDATE:

Apparently there is a function already running "onchange", so that the HTML looks this way:

```
<select name="<select name="country_List" onchange="checkCountry();" id="countries">  
<option value="">––> Select</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">Canada</option>
<option value="3">Mexico</option>"
<option value="4">Argentina</option>"
<option value="5">Australia</option>"
</select>
```

This seems to be interfering with the codes suggested for this case. Is it there any way to run the code to hide the "state" after the "onchange" function "checkCountry()" has been run?

Comment: Do you assume the jquery lib is available or not ? You put the jquery tag, but it's not clear if you want the solution to use it or not.

Comment: @QuantumLicht Yes, jquery is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to validate your html; you're missing a closing `</select>` tag. Second, the textbox has to be **disabled** when not required so that it is not included in the form data when the form is submitted. The following should meet your requirements:

```
$('#countries').on('change', function() {
    if( $.trim( this.value ) === '3' ) {
        $('#state').val('').prop('disabled', true).closest('p').hide();
    } else {
        $('#state').prop('disabled', false).closest('p').show();
    }
});
```

```js
    $('#countries').on('change', function() {
        if( $.trim( this.value ) === '3' ) {
            $('#state').val('').prop('disabled', true).closest('p').hide();
        } else {
            $('#state').prop('disabled', false).closest('p').show();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country_list" id="countries"><option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2" selected="">Canada</option>
<option value="3">Rest of the World</option>
</select>
<p><input type="text" name="state_field" value="" id="state"></p>
```

**UPDATE**

And this should meet your updated requirements; you would just update the logic so you end up with the least number of clauses or boolean expressions in the if condition:

```
$('#countries').on('change', function() {
    if( $.trim( this.value ) === '2' || $.trim( this.value ) === '1') {
        $('#state').prop('disabled', false).closest('p').show();
    } else {
        $('#state').val('').prop('disabled', true).closest('p').hide();
    }
})
.change();
```

```js
    $('#countries').on('change', function() {
        if( ['1','2'].indexOf( this.value ) > -1 ) {
            $('#state').prop('disabled', false).closest('p').show();
        } else {
            $('#state').val('').prop('disabled', true).closest('p').hide();
        }
    })
    .change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="country_list" id="countries"><option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2" selected="">Canada</option>
    <option value="3">Rest of the World</option>
    </select>
    <p><input type="text" name="state_field" value="" id="state"></p>
```

Please note that `.change()` triggers the `change` event when the page loads so that if the value is not 1 or 2, the textbox will be hidden.

Comment: that looks good but how would I go if there were more options where the field state should not appear. Say I have 20 countries but the state field should only appear for option 1 and 2. For the rest it should be invisible

Comment: how could I put a range or the values where the field should disappear?

Comment: If you have something specific, can you update the question so we're clear on what you're talking about. Please bear in mind that `$.trim( this.value ) === '2' || $.trim( this.value ) === '1'` is equivalent to `['1','2'].indexOf( $.trim( this.value ) ) > -1` ... that should give you a clue on how to use a list of values.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when using any of the posted codes. Do you know what it means:

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    checkIsoCode
    onchange

Comment: Quite likely you'll need to check the spelling of the elements selector, or the element you're trying to manipulate does not exist. Please create a jsfiddle showing this problem and we'd be glad to assist you resolve it.

Comment: I have updated the question. See the new information added after "UPDATE"

Comment: You may want to provide the `checkCountry()` function. And, I would not advise you to use inline JavaScript.

Comment: I have figured it out. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
<script>
   function show(mode)
   {
       document.getElementById('state').style.visibility = (mode) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
   }
<script>

<select name="country_list" id="countries"><option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1" onclick="show(true)">USA</option>
<option value="2" onclick="show(true)">Canada</option>
<option value="3" onclick="show(false)">Rest of the World</option>

<p><input type="text" name="state_field" value="" id="state"></p>
```

Comment: how do I set for what cases the field is visible and for what cases it isn't

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/itsazzad/c3na3aja/)

```
$( "select#countries" )
  .change(function () {
      if($("select#countries option:selected").attr("value")=="3"){
          $("select#countries").hide();
          $("#state").show();
          $("#state").val($("select#countries option:selected").text());
      }else{
          $("#state").hide();
          $("select#countries").show();
          $("#state").val("");
      }
});
$( "#state" )
  .change(function () {
      if($("#state").val()==""){
          $("#state").hide();
          $("select#countries").show();
      }else{
      }
});
```

[JSFIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/itsazzad/c3na3aja/)